# How to use my treeview subclass in qt designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I have a class myTreeView which is a subclass of QTreeView, which I am using in other widget and doing layout manually. now I want to include myTreeView in the new widget using designer so that I can avoid layout code. any suggestions/reference, how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a `QTreeView` into your layout in Qt Designer. Right click the `QTreeView`, click **Promote to...** add a **New Promoted Class** definition using the form at the bottom of the dialog.

i.e. specify the base class of your derived class as `QTreeView`, give the widget a name, and specify where Qt Design can find the header file for your derived class.

That should allow you, at a minimum, to place your widget on the form as you lay it out. It will most likely show up as a grey empty box (much like a QWidget) on the layout however when you compile and build a project using your .ui file your widget will appear.